# How to calculate Mode (Statistics) for a set of every 10 numbers in a large data set

Tags: r

Like if i have 1223455567 1777666666 i want the output be 5 an 6 .
how can i do this in R language?

i know how to find the mean for every 10 data but what i want is mode.

here is what i tried for mean

`mean10 <- aggregate(level, list(rep(1:(nrow(level) %/% n+1),each = n, len = nrow(level))), mean)[-1];`

and there is a function for mode as follow:

```
MODE <- function(dataframe){
    DF <- as.data.frame(dataframe)

    MODE2 <- function(x){      
    if (is.numeric(x) == FALSE){
        df <- as.data.frame(table(x))  
        df <- df[order(df$Freq), ]         
        m <- max(df$Freq)        
        MODE1 <- as.vector(as.character(subset(df, Freq == m)[, 1]))

        if (sum(df$Freq)/length(df$Freq)==1){
            warning("No Mode: Frequency of all values is 1", call. = FALSE)
        }else{
            return(MODE1)
        }

    }else{ 
        df <- as.data.frame(table(x))  
        df <- df[order(df$Freq), ]         
        m <- max(df$Freq)        
        MODE1 <- as.vector(as.numeric(as.character(subset(df, Freq == m)[, 1])))

        if (sum(df$Freq)/length(df$Freq)==1){
            warning("No Mode: Frequency of all values is 1", call. = FALSE)
        }else{
            return(MODE1)
        }
    }
}

return(as.vector(lapply(DF, MODE2)))
}
```

Comment: By "every 10 data" do you mean: one mode for rows 1:10, one mode for rows 2:11, one mode for rows 3:12,... or do you mean one mode for rows 1:10, one mode for rows 11:20, one mode for rows 21:30...

Comment: 1:10 11:20 21:30 like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `zoo` package to calculate a moving mode:

```
library(zoo)

# sample data
d <- data.frame(x = sample(1:3, 100, T))

# mode function (handles ties by choosing one)
my_mode <- function(x) as.numeric(which.max(table(x)))

# add moving mode as new variable
transform(d, moving_mode = rollapply(x, 10, FUN = my_mode, fill = NA))
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  y <- unique(x)
  y[which.max(tabulate(match(x, y)))]
}

library(zoo)
x<- c(1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,1,7,7,7,6,6,6,6,6,6)
rollapply(data = x, width = 10, FUN = Mode, by = 10 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Given you're not after a rolling mode but really a group mode, none of the other answers are accurate. It's actually much easier to do this in the case you have in mind; I'll use `data.table`.

```
#fixed cost: set-up of 'data.table'
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)
```

Now solving:

```
#this works on a single column;
#  the rep(...) bit is about creating the
#  sequence (1, ..., 1, 2, ..., 2, ...)
#  of integers each repeated 10 times.
#  Here, .N will give the frequency -- i.e.,
#  this first step is basically running 'table' for every 10 rows
DF[ , .N, by = .(col1, grp = rep(1:(.N %/% 10 + 1), length.out = .N)))
   #by going in descending order on frequency, we can simply 
   #  extract the first element of each 'grp' to get the mode.
   #  (this glosses over the issue of ties, but you haven't given
   #   any guidance to that end)
   ][order(-N), .SD[1L], by = grp]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always convert to `character` and see which char is max in a table. E.g.

```
> which.max(table(strsplit(as.character(1777666666),"")))
6 
2
```